# IndexOF isn't wrong, but me :)

Tags: java, string, indexof

I need help:
I'm making a program which can readout specific strings out of an html.
My Code:

```
String html = client.request(URL);
// is more or less = [html]<meta itemProp="name" content="[my target]"/> [html]

String searchString = "<meta itemProp=\"name\" content=\"";
String searchEndString = "\"/>";

while (true) {

        int from = html.indexOf(searchString);  
        if (from == -1) {
            break;
        }
        String temp = html.substring(from);
        int to = temp.indexOf(searchEndString, from);     //this is somehow -1
        String name = temp.substring(searchString.length(), to);
        // DO sth with name
        html = temp.substring(to);  
    }
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -32
>   at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source) on line 45

The `String name = temp.substring(searchString.length(), to);` throws the exception because `to` is `-1` at that point.

**Why does `int to = temp.indexOf(searchEndString, from);` result in `-1`**

I have already tried a custom `html` string, which worked.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use debugger or some System.out.println() to figure out what is the content of `temp`and `searchEndString`

Comment: Hint: Why do you pass `from` as argument to temp.indexOf()? What is `from`?

Comment: temp is `<meta itemProp="name" content="[my target]"/> [html]` and searchEndString is "\"/>" meaning `"/>`

Comment: @JB Nizet thank you so much :)